# Swap strings in Java. Beginner in Java

Tags: java, string

What I'm trying to do: Given a string from user, swap the first half with second half. If the string length is odd, take the lower first half and swap. And if the string length is 1, leave it alone.
For Example:

Input: `abcde`

Output: `cdeab`

Don't know how to deal with strings exactly in java! I'm losing confidence here..

```
import java.util.*;

class Swap {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        String s = in.nextLine();
        int length = s.length();

        System.out.println(length);

        int x = length/2;

        if (x % 2 = 0) {
            for (int i =0; i<x; i++) {
                String s[] array1 ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Click the edit link at the bottom of your question, and post the code, formatted as code and properly indented, in your question. Not in a comment. Tell us what you expect this code to do and what it does instead.

Comment: The simplest answer will involve the `length()` and `substring()` methods, and concatenation.  [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) is the javadoc for both `substring` methods.

Comment: IT just doesn't get indented!using those spaces! :/

Comment: Could you just tell me how to convert strings to char in Java?

Comment: Just use `substring()`: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm

Comment: `if (x % 2 = 0)` is NOT equality, use `==`...

Comment: To get one character out of a string: [`charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-).  Is that what you need?

Comment: By the time the `if` is reached, you've already set `x = length/2`.  Doesn't make much sense to test `x%2`.  You want to test `length%2` instead.

Comment: "*Don't know how to deal with strings exactly in Java*" then you should be reading tutorial and documentation instead of asking others to write solution for your homework. Hint: take a look at [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) method from String class.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the most efficient code I could write for it. Works with both odd and even-number length strings.

```
    String myString = "abcdef";
    String newString;
    int split = myString.length() / 2;

    newString = myString.substring(split);
    myString = myString.substring(0, split);
    newString = newString + myString;

    return newString;
```

What it is essentially doing is splitting a string in two, and adding those halves into a new string backwards. So the second half becomes the first half, and the first is now the second half.

You can of course make myString be defined by user input, or by whatever method is asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.This is to swap a string following the condition you mentioned.

```
import java.util.*;

class Swap {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string");
    String s = in.nextLine();
    int length = s.length();

    System.out.println("The length is:-"+length);

    int l=length/2;
    String st="",sw="";
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    st+=s.charAt(i);
    for(int j=l;j<length;j++)
    sw+=s.charAt(j);
    System.out.println("The new string is:-"+sw+st);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it wud be more helpful if u could explain me this part?
String st="",sw="";
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    st+=s.charAt(i);
    for(int j=l;j<length;j++)
    sw+=s.charAt(j);

Comment: The comment is going to be too big.I am going to edit my answer for you.

Comment: Changed my mind.Will post another answer to you regarding this explanation.

Comment: Thanks :)
I did some code as well. Could you check that, but its different?
Also I'd appreciate if you could provide me some links to get to know java better and easily?

How do i properly indent my code here in StackOverflow...i don't know how to use the spaces here..any easy ways?

Comment: No worries! Take your time, but do let me know how it works Saptak :)

Comment: The answer has been posted.There are many websites which are going to assist you with a lantern in your way to shake off the title "java beginner".You may follow the java tutorials at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java,or you can also follow the Oracle documentation  on java.That's upto you.Keep this in mind,these sites will only assist you.What matters in the long run is that whether you strive to excel in your objective or not.

Answer (score 0):

In order to swap the string,the string is first divided into 2 parts using the integer variable l.The whole thing is programmed in such a way that the first half of the string gets stored in the string variable st and the other half in the string variable sw.In the loop first loop iterations take place through the first half of the string,and in each iteration,each character of the first half of the string gets added to the string variable s1.After this loop the first half of the string gets stored in the variable st.
Similarly,in the second loop,we iterate through the next half of the string and the other half of the string gets stored in the string variable sw following a similar process.
Then,the second half of the string is printed before the first half in the statement
System.out.println("The new string is:-"+sw+st);and this is how the string is swapped.

Comment: Alright (Y)
This line confuses me though : String st="",sw="";
What is it doing?

As you said..."and in each iteration,each character of the first half of the string gets added to the string variable s1."
where is the variable s1?

Comment: Sorry pal.That would be st,not s1.Just ,made a mistake there.

Comment: Those statements are to initialize the string objects with a null string for each of the two.Otherwise,how can I store the two halves of the string in them :-)?

Comment: I initialized them with a null string for each so that I can add up the characters of each half of the string and store them in the variables st and sw.

Comment: Thanks!!In the "comment-chat" with you,I have just won the commentator badge,which amounts to 6 in total.:-)

Comment: And 1 more thing.If you do find my answer and the subsequent explanations satisfacory,PLZ vote it up.I am lacking reputations.I am a bit of a "selfish-giant",you know.:-)

Comment: Yup, I understood once I read 'null string' in your comment. I was looking at it differently! :P

Comment: and Congrats! Thanks alot to you though! xD

Comment: I tried to 'VoteUp', my reputation doesn't let me do that :/ :(

Comment: Is it?Well,does it not show a tick mark beside the answer which is not clicked?Click it,then.The tick sign will turn green in colour.